# MySQL index not used

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

have some table with index for two columns (user_id,date)
and SQL query

```
select  user_id, stat.in, stat.out, stat.time, date
from stat
where user_id in (select id from users force index (street_id) where street_id=30);
```

or

```
select  user_id, stat.in, stat.out, stat.time, date 
from stat where user_id in (select id from users force index (street_id) where street_id=30)
and date between STR_TO_DATE('2010-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') and TR_TO_DATE('2014-05-22 23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

In two case index must work, but I sink problem in `in` statement. If it's possible, how make it work?
Explain:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows     | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | stat  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL  | 32028701 | Using where              |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | users | ref  | street_id     | street_id | 8       | const |      650 | Using where; Using index |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
```

if search with one user_id index work

```
explain select  user_id, stat.in, stat.out, stat.time, date
from stat
where user_id=3991;
```

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stat  | ref  | user_id_2     | user_id_2 | 8       | const | 2973 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+-------+
```

Comment: can you show the indexes available in both tables , I am sure the `IN` clause is killing everything.

Comment: another indexes of both  table don't help in this case, they are for another columns.

Comment: Also share the complete table strucutures if possible with some data in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: MySQL is notoriously bad with subqueries and `IN` conditions. If you want to make use of the index, you will probably need to find a different approach (e.g. using a JOIN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing in the query the IN clause is creating havoc and if I am not wrong the indexes are  not done properly.

So here is how it should be lets say the tables are as

```
create table users (id int, name varchar(100),street_id int);
insert into users values 
(1,'a',20),(2,'b',30),(3,'c',10),(4,'d',20),(5,'e',10),(6,'f',40),(7,'g',20),
(8,'h',10),(9,'i',10),(10,'j',40);


create table stat (user_id int ,`in` int, `out` int, time int , date date);
insert into stat values
(1,1,1,20,'2014-01-01'),
(1,1,1,20,'2014-01-02'),
(3,1,1,20,'2014-01-01'),
(2,1,1,20,'2014-01-01'),
(4,1,1,20,'2014-01-02'),
(6,1,1,20,'2014-01-02'),
(7,1,1,20,'2014-01-02'),
(8,1,1,20,'2014-01-02'),
(1,1,1,20,'2014-01-02'),
(2,1,1,20,'2014-01-02'),
(3,1,1,20,'2014-01-03'),
(4,1,1,20,'2014-01-04'),
(5,1,1,20,'2014-01-04'),
(6,1,1,20,'2014-01-04'),
(7,1,1,20,'2014-01-04'),
(2,1,1,20,'2014-01-04'),
(3,1,1,20,'2014-01-04'),
(4,1,1,20,'2014-01-05'),
(5,1,1,20,'2014-01-05'),
(6,1,1,20,'2014-01-05'),
(7,1,1,20,'2014-01-05'),
(8,1,1,20,'2014-01-05'),
(9,1,1,20,'2014-01-05'),
(10,1,1,20,'2014-01-05'),
(1,1,1,20,'2014-01-06'),
(4,1,1,20,'2014-01-06');
```

Now add some indexes on the table

```
alter table users add index id_idx (id);
alter table users add index street_idx(street_id);

alter table stat add index user_id_idx(user_id);
```

Now if we execute the same query that you are trying to do using explain yields

```
EXPLAIN
select  user_id, stat.`in`, stat.`out`, stat.time, date
from stat
where user_id in (select id from users force index (street_id) where street_id=30);


+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | stat  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL  |   26 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | users | ref  | street_idx    | street_idx | 5       | const |    1 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

It still looks like trying to scan the entire table.

Now lets modify the query and use JOIN and see what explain has to say, note that I have index on both table for the joining key and which are of same type and size.

```
EXPLAIN
select
s.user_id,
s.`in`,
s.`out`,
s.time,
s.date
from stat s
join users u on u.id = s.user_id 
where u.street_id=30 ;

+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys     | key         | key_len | ref       | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | ref  | id_idx,street_idx | street_idx  | 5       | const     |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | ref  | user_id_idx       | user_id_idx | 5       | test.u.id |    3 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+-------------+
```

Better hun ?? Now lets try a range search

```
EXPLAIN
select
s.user_id,
s.`in`,
s.`out`,
s.time,
s.date
from stat s
join users u on u.id = s.user_id 
where 
u.street_id=30 
and s.date between '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-06'
;


+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys     | key         | key_len | ref       | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | ref  | id_idx,street_idx | street_idx  | 5       | const     |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | ref  | user_id_idx       | user_id_idx | 5       | test.u.id |    3 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+-------------+
```

Still better right ??

So the underlying agenda is try avoiding `IN` queries. Use `JOIN` on indexed column and for search columns indexed them properly.